# removing elements using python and lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I need to remove the following from this xml -

```
<entry>
    <id>1234</id>
    <title>hello</title>
    <source>com.server.webclient.xxx</source>
    <xxx:component>
        <xxx:id>2134</xxx:id>
        <xxx:name>name</xxx.name>
    </xxx:component>
</entry>
```

What I want to do is remove `<entry>`, `<id>`, `<title>` and `<source>`

My code is trying to just delete ID right now but isn't returning an error but it isn't removing the values.

```
with open('c:\\temp\\%s.xml' % args.componentName, 'w') as f:
    xmlObject = etree.fromstring(r.content)
    for elem in xmlObject.xpath( '//id' ) :
        elem.remove(elem)
    f.write(etree.tostring(xmlObject, pretty_print=True))
```

This is what I want my XML to look like -

```
<xxx:component>
    <xxx:id>2134</xxx:id>
    <xxx:name>name</xxx.name>
</xxx:component>
```

Comment: If you are not getting any error, then that means the `xmlObject.xpath('//id')` returned no result, since if you every try to do - `elem.remove(elem)` , you would face the issue - `ValueError: Element is not a child of this node.`

Comment: Given that, wouldn't it be easier to just get the `<xxx:component>` element from the xml and write that alone to another xml file?

Comment: on your second point more likely that would be the better solution?  I'll see what my googlefu turns up on that as an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier option for you to achieve what you want would be to find the `<xxx:component>` element inside the `<entry>` component and write that to the file.

Example -

```
with open('c:\\temp\\%s.xml' % args.componentName, 'w') as f:
    xmlObject = etree.fromstring(r.content)
    reqElem = xmlObject.xpath('//xxx:component',namespaces=ns)   #ns should have the `xxx` prefix and whatever its actual namespace is
    if len(reqElem) == 1:
        f.write(etree.tostring(reqElem[0], pretty_print=True))
```

Comment: Thanks!  Update the tags to make them valid.  I'm just figuring out the namespaces issue now.  The namespace is this `<tes:Variable xmlns:tes="http://www.tidalsoftware.com/client/tesservlet">`

Comment: Then ns should be a dictionary like - `ns = {'tes':'http://www.tidalsoftware.com/client/tesservlet'}`

Comment: ok I had that right :)  Problem is that it's returning a 0kb file

Comment: Maybe try putting an else part to the code i gave and print if it goes to else, and then check why its going there?

Comment: put in an else to just print reqElem and getting empty `[]`

Comment: What is the exact xpath you are using?

Comment: `xmlObject.xpath('//tes:Variable', namespaces={'tes':'http://www.tidalsoftware.com/client/tesservlet'})`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87613/discussion-between-anand-s-kumar-and-whoisearth).